# I have a problem with a loop code in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, seleniumbase

- ### **Please, this is my first project, I'm still learning Python. Please be patient with me. Thank you for your efforts**

In the first test, it finds the elements without any issue.

I have a condition if the element is found "

```
def Check_Appointment(sb):
    while True:
        no_appointment_message = "We are sorry but no appointment slots are currently available. New slots open at regular intervals, please try again later"
        element_text = sb.get_text('/html/body/app-root/div/div/app-eligibility-criteria/section/form/mat-card[1]/form/div[4]')

        if no_appointment_message in element_text:
            go_to_homepage(sb)
            print("We are sorry but no appointment slots are currently available.")
            go_to_homepage(sb)
        else:
            print("Earliest available slot for Applicants")
            playsound('./Music.mp3')
            print("Attention Alarm >>>>> Success")
            get_appointment_data(sb)
            break  # Break the loop when an appointment is found
```

", it returns me to the home page to restart the steps anew

During the repetition it informs me that the element is not found

```
error encountered: Message: Element {#mat-select-value-1} was not present after 7 seconds!
```

I want the browser to continue and repeat the steps until the element content changes.

Here are all the codes

```
def click_new_booking(sb):
    sleep(5)
    # Search For Application Button
    sb.highlight_click('/html/body/app-root/div/div/app-dashboard/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/button')  
    print("Start New Booking (Button) click >>>>> Success")
    sleep(3)
    select_first_category(sb)
```

```
def select_first_category(sb):
    sleep(1)
    sb.highlight(".mt-15")
    sb.click('#mat-select-value-1') # Opens (Choose your Visa Application Centre) 'the Drop-down menu
    sb.click('span:contains("Application Centre")')
    select_second_category(sb)
```

```
def select_second_category(sb):
    sleep(1)
    sb.highlight_click('#mat-select-value-5') # Opens (Choose your appointment category) 'the Drop-down menu
    sb.click('//*[@id="mat-option-2"]/span')
    select_last_category(sb)
```

```
def select_last_category(sb):
    sleep(1)
    sb.highlight_click('#mat-select-value-3') # Opens (Choose your sub-category) 'the Drop-down menu
    sb.click('//*[@id="mat-option-3"]/span')   
    Check_Appointment(sb)
```

```
def Check_Appointment(sb):
    while True:
        no_appointment_message = "no appointment"
        element_text = sb.get_text('/html/body/app-root/div/div/app-eligibility-criteria/section/form/mat-card[1]/form/div[4]')

        if no_appointment_message in element_text:
            go_to_homepage(sb)
        else:
            print("Earliest available slot for Applicants")
            playsound('./Music.mp3')
            print("Attention Alarm >>>>> Success")
            get_appointment_data(sb)
            break  # Break the loop when an appointment is found
```

```
def get_appointment_data(sb):
    # Search For Continue Button
    sb.highlight_click('button.mat-focus-indicator')  
    print("Continue 1 Enabled (Button) click >>>>> Success")
    sleep(4)
```

```
def go_to_homepage(sb):
    sb.highlight_click('/html/body/app-root/div/header/div[1]/div/a/img')  
    print("Back to Booking There is No Dates >>>>> Success")
    click_new_booking(sb)
```

```
with SB(uc=True, demo=True) as sb:
    while True:
        try:
            open_the_form_turnstile_page(sb)
            click_turnstile_and_verify(sb)
            def click_new_booking(sb):
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'error encountered: {e}')
        finally:        
            sleep(2)
            quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message that you are having

```
error encountered: Message: Element {#mat-select-value-1} was not present after 7 seconds
```

It seems that you are having a statement like this previously in the code

```
driver.implicitly_wait(7)
```

To solve the issue you might need to use explicit wait, which would be waiting till some specified condition. [Documentation of Explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "#mat-select-value-1"))
```

The above code would click the element when the presence of the element is located under **10** seconds, and if it is not found then it would throw an error. You might need to check for other conditions too, like **element_to_be_clickable** instead of just **presence_of_element_located**, to solve this.

After the condition is satisfied it would move to the next statement which can be a click statement.